# Is there a way to identify whether a PDF is an image PDF in Java?

Tags: java, tesseract, pdfbox

I'm converting PDF to scrape some data using java. I'm using Tesseract to scrape image PDFs and PDFBox to scrape non-image PDFs. Normally we can check whether PDF is an image or not by selecting text from PDF, if you are unable to highlight text from PDF then it is image PDF.
I want to know is there a way in java to find out whether PDF is an image PDF or non-image PDF?

Answer (score 0):

You can use PDFBox to pull out the text from PDF. If there isn't much text, or the retrieved text is gibberish, it's more likely an image PDF.

Comment: Yes, it worked if the response is empty but the question still remains, if its garbage data then how can you identify this at runtime?